# Resource is not created in firefox addon

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I try to create the image resource for my firefox addon. I try that:

```
var {Cc,Ci,Cu,Cr,Cm} = require("chrome");
var {Services} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
let res = Services.io.getProtocolHandler("resource").QueryInterface(Ci.nsIResProtocolHandl‌​er); 
res.setSubstitution("test-addon/data", Services.io.newURI('file://C:/Averenges.jpg', null, null));
```

It worked but only once.I don't understand why. After i start that code and it run but nothing happens.

Comment: Are you sure going to `resource://test-addon/data` is not taking you that image?

Comment: Yes  i sure. NOTHING! May be it somehow  relative to browser?

Comment: I try use nsIFile to copy image to resource://firefox-addon/data. I create `nsILocalFile.initWithPath('C:\\Averenges.jpg');` For function `copyTo(
  in nsIFile newParentDir,
  in AString newName
);` I need to get nsIFile from `resouce://firefox-addon/data`. 1) Can i solve problem via that way. 2)And  how to do  `resouce://firefox-addon/data` nslFile type?

Comment: I don't understand your question can you please reword.